# laravel validation add custom var

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wan't to give user ability to limit upload file size.

```
    $uploadSize = Settings::where('id','=','1')->first();
    $upSz=$uploadSize->uploadSize;
    $upMz="'max:".$upSz."'";
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => $upMz,
        'file' => 'mimes:doc,docx,xslx,ppt,pptx,zip,rar,pdf',
         ]);
```

And it throws out error

```
Method [validate'max] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have extra quotes, correct:

```
$upMz="max:".$upSz."";
$this->validate($request, [
        'file' => $upMz,
        'file' => 'mimes:doc,docx,xslx,ppt,pptx,zip,rar,pdf',
         ]);
```